# Rails 4, PostgreSQL: convert results of find_by_sql aggregate functions into OpenStruct

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, aggregate-functions, find-by-sql

Working on a report/metrics page and I need to optimize the queries as much as I can so I am using find_by_sql for efficiency.

One of my queries is doing some aggregate functions where I return a count and some sums.  I'm assigning the results of this query into instance variables for a model.

I have working code, but the code scares me.  I have read the official Ruby/Rails docs on the methods used, but I still think there's something wrong with what I'm doing.

```
def initialize(args)
  @loans_count           = stats.loans_count
  @total_fees_in_cents   = stats.total_fees_in_cents
  @total_amount_in_cents = stats.total_amount_in_cents
end

def stats
  @stats ||= find_stats
end

def find_stats
  if single_year?
    loans = Loan.find_by_sql(["SELECT count(*) as loans_count, sum(amount) as total_amount_in_cents, sum(fee) as total_fees_in_cents FROM loans WHERE account_id = ? AND year = ? LIMIT 1", @account_id, @year]).first
  else
    loans = Loan.find_by_sql(["SELECT count(*) as loans_count, sum(amount) as total_amount_in_cents, sum(fee) as total_fees_in_cents FROM loans WHERE account_id = ? LIMIT 1", @account_id]).first
  end

  # Store results in OpenStruct for ease of access later on
  OpenStruct.new(
    loans_count: loans.loans_count || 0,
    total_fees_in_cents: loans.total_fees_in_cents || 0,
    total_amount_in_cents: loans.total_amount_in_cents || 0
  )
end
```

**Concerns**

1. `find_by_sql` is supposed to return an array; the SQL will always return a row, even if no matches are found (null values, but a valid row). However, is there a reason I shouldn't call `.first` on the returned array? I'm afraid of hitting `[].first => nil` in some case I didn't anticipate.
2. Is my method of "caching" the result using the `stats` method an appropriate method of only querying the DB 1 time? It seems like a lot of code and methods just to get some aggregate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,

There is two ways to look at this problem...

## Method 1

I think I can address both questions with one answer here (^_-), and the key is to address your fear.

You're mainly worried about the whole `[].first => nil`. Second your worried about DB efficiency. Thirdly, you want to make this clean and re-factored (Good for you!).

Your answer...let PostgreSQL do this work for you, and force it to return a non-nil answer every time.  Get it?

1. There's no need for the `OpenStruct` because your labels in your SQL query are the same.
2. Use the PostgreSQL function `COALESCE()` to force the null to be a zero.
3. You 'could' make all of this a one-liner, but let's chop it up a bit for ease of the reader.
4. This is already a summation query, you don't need the `LIMIT 1`.

Let's rewrite the code:

```
def initialize(args)
  @loans_count           = stats.loans_count
  @total_fees_in_cents   = stats.total_fees_in_cents
  @total_amount_in_cents = stats.total_amount_in_cents
end

def stats
  loans = Loan.select("count(*) as loans_count, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as total_amount_in_cents, COALESCE(sum(fee), 0) as total_fees_in_cents").where(account_id: @account_id)

  loans = loans.where(year: @year) if single_year?

  loans.first
end
```

## Method 2

I personally think you are overly worried about the DB efficiency thing. You can always look at your development/production logs to read what is actually being outputted to the PSQL server, but I'm pretty sure it's close to the same thing your doing here.

Also, if I remember correctly, the DB query isn't actually executed UNTIL you want the data. During that time, ActiveRecord is just preparing the QUERY string.

`.to_i` will convert your null to zero.

Let's rewrite the code:

```
def initialize(args)
  stats = Loan.where(account_id: @account_id)
  stats = stats.where(year: @year) if single_year?
  stats.first

  @loans_count           = stats.count
  @total_fees_in_cents   = stats.sum(:fee).to_i
  @total_amount_in_cents = stats.sum(:amount).to_i
end
```

Comment: Eric, that's an awesome job of cleaning up the code! It looks much cleaner and easier to read than what I was doing. I'll see if I can update the code this weekend.  I actually didn't know about PG's "coalesce" function. And believe it or not, your code actually answered another question I had just today on a completely separate project (dealing with `find_by_sql()` with `where()` issues).  Thanks for this!